# Cloudera CDH 5.x on Ubuntu 17

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera-cdh, bigdata

Can CDH 5.x be installed on Ubuntu 17? According to the Cloudera site, they have support till Ubuntu 16.
I am new to big data, so please pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score -1):

CDH is Cloudera's Distribution including Apache Hadoop so it is a Virtual Machine which has everything pre-installed so it doesn't matter on what machine you use that VM. So yes, VM can be run on Ubuntu 17.04 using VMware or VirtualBox.